# How do I check for a blank user role in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles

Is there a quick way to check to see if a user is not in a role?

I have an application where we are using roles but by default when you create a user, that user does not get assigned a role.  I want to set a check on a method that says

```
 if user does not have a role - redirect to another page.
```

I can easily check if the user is in a specific role but I cannot seem to find a way to check if a user doesn't have a role at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What membership system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the users roles like this:

```
 var principal = (RolePrincipal)User;
 if (!principal.GetRoles().Any())
 {
     // Has no roles.
 }
```